# Tabular data representation

Tags: entities, commerce

I am building a demo site, trying to learn commerce kickstarter. 
I figured out a lot of it but i wanted to add something more to the items.

If you click this link : http://www.sigmaphoto.com/product/sd15-digital-slr-camera 
I don't own that or promote that site , i found it on drupale commerce kickstarter showcase. 
My question is how can i create tabs that are like under the pictures. 
OVERVIEW | TECH SPEC | ACCESSORIES

Do you need to create a view or is there a field that you can add so you can input the data in the content type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is actually a few modules that will allow you to get tabs in your content easily. The one I use is **Quicktabs**, listed below along with some alternative modules.

1. **Quicktabs** (module) - https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs
2. **Field Group** (module) - https://drupal.org/project/field_group (has tabs support)
3. **jQuery Tabs Field** (module) - https://drupal.org/project/field_jquery_tabs

Comment: BTW, "Tabular data" usually refers to <table> data/content, in fact similar to the design under the "TECH SPEC" tab of your example site link. For reference, that type of formatting will require an additional module add-on for Views.

Comment: Hi thanks i lot. I have opted for jQuery tabs field because i can put it in the content type. I have used Quicktabs but this is a much better solution for my current situation. 
I have another question, now i have added the tabs field but they stay (if you look at the link im my post) under the BUY NOW and FIND A DEALER. The tabs are not full width like in the link (from camera to find a dealer). How can i do that ???

Comment: Full width tabs is more of a CSS (theme) issue, not the module itself.